# Getting 'Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompletionListener()'.......' while trying to place some code inside builder.setPositiveButton's onClick() method

Tags: android, firebase, android-alertdialog, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to place some code inside `AlertDialog.Builder`'s `builder.setPositiveButton` method.

The problem is that I'm getting the following error: `Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompletionListener(anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompletionListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>)`

Here's the code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                builder.setView(R.layout.customlayout);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

//error from below line

                   mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail.getText().toString(), userPassword.getText().toString())
                                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        Log.d("signUpSuccessful", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Sign up failed. Please retry.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                            snackbar.show();
                                        }

                                        // ...
                                    }
                                });

//upto this line
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

What's wrong here?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 33):

```
addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
```

"this" in this line means your DialogInterface.OnClickListener , you should check what kind of params this method needs, if Context, try to change it to this

```
addOnCompleteListener(YourActivityName.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
```

Comment: Excellent, I was copying exactly what Google documentation has. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Your issue happen with this line code:

```
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
```

Here `this` parameter compiler let as `.OnClickListener` insted of your activity context.

[image]

**The solutin is so simple:**

```
.addOnCompleteListener(ActivityName.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
```

Insted of `this` use `ActivityName.this`.