# Unchecked assignment warning while sending email verification using firebase for android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Below image shows the Firebase code snippet used for sending email verification to my app users when they sign up.

[image]

The highlighted area in the image gives the following warning:

```
Unchecked assignment: 'anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener' to 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<java.lang.Void>' less... (Ctrl+F1)

Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:

  void f(HashMap map) {
    map.put("key", "value");
  }

Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.
```

I am unable to interpret the warning. How could I get rid of this warning? Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to pass 'SignUpActivity.this' instead of 'this' in addOnCompleteListener(...)

Comment: The warning is still there.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486937/getting-cannot-resolve-method-addoncompletionlistener-while-trying?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

`new OnCompleteListener()` should be replaced with

```
new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
```